# Is it possible to compare two values in a row and fetch the desired one, but both the values matches the regex written

Tags: regex

text = "Happy 4/20 from the team! 13/10 congrats..after so many contents"

I want to fetch only 13/10 which is the rating. I have written regex

```
(\d+\.\d+|\d+)/(((?=10)10)|([1-9]\d+))
```

but it fetches the first one(4/20).
Is this possible to achieve using regex?

Comment: Is there certain logic to select only the second? What if there are 3 occurrences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of your pattern `(?=10)10` you can omit the positive lookahead because that says if what is on the right is 10, then match 10. This part `[1-9]\d+` matches 10 and above so 10 is already in the range.

You could use a capturing group with a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) `{2}` to repeat that group.

Your pattern can also be written as `\d+(?:\.\d+)?/[1-9]\d+)`

To get the second group, you might use:

```
^(?:.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?/[1-9]\d+)){2}
```

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `.*?` Match any char non greedy
  - `(` Capturing group

    - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits, optionally match a dot and 1+ digits
    - `/` Match `/`
    - `[1-9]\d+` Match 10 and above
  - `)` Close capturing group
- `){2}` Close non capturing group and repeat 2 times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BJcKG7/1)

Comment: this query is fetching the text too. i want only the ratings. text_1 - He's in a predicament. 9/10 help is on the way buddy text_2 - Happy 4/20 from the team! 13/10 congrats..after so many contents. From both texts, i want 9/10(from text_1) and 13/10(from text_2). Please help.

Comment: Your value is in the first capturing group. In the regex101 link it is highlighted in green

Comment: The first sentence contains a single value so you can omit the quantifier. Use `^.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?/[1-9]\d+)`

Comment: i want the regex to match both texts. text_1 which has only one rating is not matched by the exp. Is it to possible to match it?

Comment: If you want to match the last occurrence only use `\d+(?:\.\d+)?/[1-9]\d+(?!.*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?/[1-9]\d+))`  https://regex101.com/r/BJcKG7/2